# Powershell: "Interface not supported" ComException when setting RDOSession.MAPIObject

Tags: powershell, outlook-addin, outlook-redemption, outlook-2019

I want to add some Exchange Online Shared Mailboxes to the current user in Outlook. Trying to logon to the MAPI Session throws the Error "Interface not supported"

This is the Powershell Code I´d want to start with:

```
# Create Outlook application object
$outlook = New-Object -ComObject Outlook.Application
$session = New-Object -ComObject Redemption.RDOSession

# Get the MAPI namespace
$namespace = $outlook.GetNamespace("MAPI")
$namespace.Logon()
#$inbox = $namespace.GetDefaultFolder(6)

$recipientName = "xxx@yyy.com";
$Recipient = $namespace.CreateRecipient($recipientName);
$Recipient.Resolve();

$session.MAPIOBJECT = $outlook.Session.MAPIOBJECT

Interface not supported
At line:15 char:1
+ $session.MAPIOBJECT = $outlook.Session.MAPIOBJECT
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
+ CategoryInfo          : OperationStopped: (:) [], COMException
+ FullyQualifiedErrorId : System.Runtime.InteropServices.COMException
```

OS Version: Windows11 23H2
Outlook Version: Microsoft® Outlook® 2019 MSO (Version 2312 Build 16.0.17126.20132) 32-bit
Redemption Version: 6.4.0.6234 32/64Bit

I´ve tried using this fix, but no change...
http://www.dimastr.com/redemption/Outlook_2013_C2R_fix.ZIP

I'm not sure what´s missing...
Is anyone using Powershell to something similar?
Maybe someone can point me in the right direction?
Thx...

Comment: What is the Outlook bitness? Is your code running in 32 or 64 bit?

Comment: Hi Dmitry 
Sorry, there was a formating issue:
Outlook Version: Microsoft® Outlook® 2019 MSO (Version 2312 Build 16.0.17126.20132) 32-bit
I am using the 32-bit Version

Comment: please send a message to redemption (at) dimastr (dot) com, and i will send you the debug version of the dll.

Comment: Hi Dmitry. Thanks for your response. In the meantime I figured it out. It was a loading issue. The Redemption.RDOSession was loaded in the wrong space.